# Mongodb: How to return just the embedded document with aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is the doc structure where offers and bids is sub-documents. I use mongoosejs as ORM.

```
var user = {
    name : 'polk',
    offers: [{
        title: '1',
        tags: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        bids: [{
            _id: 1      
            name: 'jose', 
            age: 18
        }, {
            _id: 2
            name: 'carlos', 
            age: 19
        }]
    },{
        title: '2',
        tags: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        bids: [{
            _id: 3
            name: 'gomes', 
            age: 21
        }, {
            _id: 4
            name: 'fernando', 
            age: 31
        }]
    }]
};
```

What i need? This sub-document:

```
{
    _id: 4
    name: 'fernando', 
    age: 31
}
```

Using? Aggregation framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows with Aggregation Framework :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$unwind : "$offers"},
    {$unwind : "$offers.bids"},
    {$match : {"offers.bids._id" : 4}},
    {$project : {_id : "$offers.bids._id", 
                 name : "$offers.bids.name", 
                 age : "$offers.name.age"
    }}
)
```

Comment: Hi! Very thanks! I do this:

    `db.registers.aggregate(
 {$match : {"_id" : ObjectId("52d93f9331065a8e76061646")}},
 {$unwind: '$offers'},
 {$unwind: '$offers.bids'},
 {$match: {"offers.bids.name":"fernando"}},
 {$project: {'_id':0, 'bid' : '$offers.bids'}});`